# Срезы python как правильно?

Tags: python, slice

Я только начал изучать python и столкнулся проблемой ...
Есть список со 100 и больше элементов мне нухно выбрать с 1 по 6 через 10 т. е. 1-6,11-16,21-26 и т.д.

```
mylist=list(range(200))
x = milist[0:6:10]
print(x)
выводит [0]
```

как записать правильно используя [::]

Comment: Нужно выбрать диапазоны индексов или значений элементов?

Comment: ```0:6:10``` это значит брать 0 а потом брать 0 + 10, так как диапазон ограничен цифрой 6 значит результат только первое число = 0

Comment: А что значит "с 1 по 6"? В Пайтоне нумерация идет с 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно через срезы. В этом варианте не важно какой длинны список и не важно из каких данных, выведет из каждого десятка по шесть элементов начиная со следующего за начальным из текущего десятка...

```
mylist=list(range(200))
c = 0
res = []
while c < len(mylist):
    res += mylist[c+1:c+7:]
    c += 10
print(res)
```

И учтите что в Python нумерация индексов начинается с 0.

Comment: mylist=list(range(200))
c = 0
res = []
while c < len(mylist):
    res += mylist[c+1:c+7:]
    c += 10
print(res) понравилось больше

Answer (score 3):

Одним срезом здесь не обойтись - их придется комбинировать - отдельно срезы для чисел, заканчивающихся на 1, потом на 2 и т.д.

Можно использовать остаток от деления (для неотрицательных чисел) - такое решение будет более элегантным:

```
res = [x for x in mylist if x % 10 < 7]
```

если в вашем списке будут и отрицательные числа, тогда можно сделать так - это будет работать как для положительных так и для отрицательных:

```
res = [x for x in mylist if abs(x) % 10 < 7]
```

---

немного извращенный вариант, который использует `sum()` и срезы:

```
res = sorted(sum((mylist[i:len(mylist):10] for i in range(7)), []))
```

Answer (score 3):

**вариант через срезы**

```
data = [i for i in range(100)] # выборка для тестирования

res = []

for i in range(len(data) // 10 + 1):
    res += data[1 + 10 * i: 7 + 10 * i]

print(res)
```

**более короткий вариант через срезы:**

```
res = []

for i in range(1, len(data), 10):
    res += data[i: i + 6]
```

**однострочный вариант (спасибо MaxU):**

```
res = sum((data[i: i + 6] for i in range(1, len(data), 10)), [])
```

Comment: да, я тоже параллельно с вам к этому варианту пришел: `sum((mylist[i:len(mylist):10] for i in range(7)), [])` ;)

Comment: да, хотел тоже через суммы сделать, но сначала решил в лоб попробовать